# Is there a way to listen undo / redo stack events in CKEditor 5

Tags: ckeditor5

I would like to automatically save the content of the CKEditor 5 on the server as the user edits it.

I could listen to the [change:data](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_document-Document.html#event-change:data) event, but it gets triggered on each keystroke. So I would need to implement some kind of debouncing strategy to avoid flooding the server.

Which brings me to the undo / redo stack. The [Undo](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_undo_undo-Undo.html) plugin seems to be doing a good job at batching changes (luckily you don't get one entry per keystroke!), so I was thinking to watch the stack and trigger a save each time an entry is added (or is done or undone).

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy, I just learned about the [autosave feature](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/saving-data.html#autosave-feature) that solves this problem. Nevermind the undo / redo stack then.